# WPF Program Issue in XAML not displaying Buttons properly

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm having an issue in moving a WPF program from "**Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop**" to "**Visual Studio Community 2015**".

My original WPF program was created in "**VS Express 2013 for Windows Desktop**". It relied on being able to embed a Grid into a Button. Onto that Grid (within the Button), I would put rectangular shapes. It works fine in **VS Express 2013** but does not work correctly in **VS Community 2015**.

The example below was created in **VS Express 2013**. It correctly shows both a Red Bordered Rectangle...and a Black Button with a White Cross inside.

```
<Window x:Class="TestErrors.MainWindow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
  <Canvas>
      <Rectangle
      Stroke="Red"
      StrokeThickness="10"
      Width="50"
      Height="50"
      Canvas.Left="75"
      Canvas.Top="20"/>
      <Button
          Width="0"
          Height="0"
          Canvas.Left="100"
          Canvas.Top="100">
          <Canvas>
              <Rectangle
              Fill="Black"
              Width="30"
              Height="30"
              Canvas.Left="-15"
              Canvas.Top="-15"/>
              <Rectangle
              Fill="White"
              Width="4"
              Height="20"
              Canvas.Left="-2"
              Canvas.Top="-10"/>
              <Rectangle
              Fill="White"
              Width="20"
              Height="4"
              Canvas.Left="-10"
              Canvas.Top="-2"/>
          </Canvas>
      </Button>
  </Canvas>
</Window>
```

[image]

The above image for **VS Express 2013** is correct...the Black button with white cross is displayed correctly.

The identical XAML in **Visual Studio Community 2015** in the example below, shows only the Red Rectangle.  It is not working as I expected.

```
<Window x:Class="TestErrors.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestErrors"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
  <Canvas>
      <Rectangle
      Stroke="Red"
      StrokeThickness="10"
      Width="50"
      Height="50"
      Canvas.Left="75"
      Canvas.Top="20"/>
      <Button
          Width="0"
          Height="0"
          Canvas.Left="100"
          Canvas.Top="100">
          <Canvas>
              <Rectangle
              Fill="Black"
              Width="30"
              Height="30"
              Canvas.Left="-15"
              Canvas.Top="-15"/>
              <Rectangle
              Fill="White"
              Width="4"
              Height="20"
              Canvas.Left="-2"
              Canvas.Top="-10"/>
              <Rectangle
              Fill="White"
              Width="20"
              Height="4"
              Canvas.Left="-10"
              Canvas.Top="-2"/>
          </Canvas>
      </Button>
  </Canvas>
</Window>
```

[image]

Where is the Black Button with the White Cross inside? What has changed to break my original code?

Answer (score 1):

Your Button Width and Height are set to 0. Change the values to fit your needs or choose an approach without button.

Comment: Yes, I know the Height and Width are set to 0. And it works fine in VS Express 2013. I have a huge program written that relies on treating the buttons this way. I don't know why the behavior has changed in the newer versions of VS and WPF.

Comment: All changes are documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Nothing jumps out in the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question.
I found the solution to the problem.
Apparently older versions of WPF worked with the following code

```
 <Button
      Width="0"
      Height="0"
```

The old versions considered these "0" settings as "auto".
But now you must specifically use the word "auto" or "Auto"...."0" will no longer give the desired results.

```
 <Button
      Width="Auto"
      Height="Auto"

 <Button
      Width="auto"
      Height="auto"
```

Both of the above fix the issue.